# Jquery how to loop data in a specific div

Tags: jquery, html, loops, each

In my page i have a div id="result" and this div already contain data.

Then i have a ajax call to retrieve loop data.

```
$.each(data, function(name, value) {
                document.write(value.email);
              });
// i tried  .html("#result")  but not working.
```

How can i place these loop data into the div id="result" and replaced the previous content.

Comment: for example: `$('#result').html(value.email);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var html = '';
$.each(data, function(name, value) {
    html += value.email;
});

$('#result').html( html );
```

I think, as you're loop over data, it seems you've multiple emeil addressess. So you can make a string of all loop data (email) and then set that as `html()` to `#request`, instead of appending to `#result` within loop again and again.

`.html()` will replace previous data and update that `#request` content with new result.

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is incorrect.  You want:

```
$.each(data, function(name, value) {
    $("#result").html(value.email);
});
```

See [the method's documentation](http://api.jquery.com/html/)

Comment: Sorry, i typed it wrong. I actually used yours but not working because it doesn't loop the data. But nvm i got the answer from @thecodeparadox.

Answer (score 1):

you are almost close , but you need to build up the html first and then write it to the div content..

```
var html = '';
$.each(data, function(name, value) {
     html += value.email;
 });

$("#result").empty().append(html);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to append the data to your result div:

```
var resultElement = $("#result");
$.each(data, function(name, value) {
    resultElement.append(value.email);
});
```

What you were doing is writing to the document instead of the `result` div.